# Unable to connect to python iothub

Tags: python, azure

Im trying to install python packages for azure iothub and connect to it using Ubuntu-14.04 but get some errors.

Here is the error.

### Couldn't find SharedAccessKeyName in connection string

```
(env) pr@pr-ubuntu:~/azure-iot-sdk-python/service/samples$ python iothub_devicetwin_sample.py 

Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
IoT Hub Service Client for Python

Starting the IoT Hub Service Client DeviceTwin Python sample...
    Connection string = HostName=bossatest.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=robot1;SharedAccessKey=aI2/uTjcQxmFv4Ya4TgGUW4tYvkDTjbrGG7cB5ogVfU=
    Device ID         = robot1
Error: Time:Tue Jun 13 06:38:38 2017 File:/home/prem/azure-iot-sdk-python/c/iothub_service_client/src/iothub_service_client_auth.c Func:IoTHubServiceClientAuth_CreateFromConnectionString Line:83 Couldn't find SharedAccessKeyName in connection string

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iothub_devicetwin_sample.py", line 66, in <module>
    iothub_devicetwin_sample_run()
  File "iothub_devicetwin_sample.py", line 36, in iothub_devicetwin_sample_run
    print ( "Unexpected error {0}" % iothub_error )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information, based on the sample source code from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/5af0e09e09ae2ba41c1e6b70efa2f1d431a61a26/service/samples/iothub_devicetwin_sample.py), the issue was caused by the connection string you used which be missing the `SharedAccessKeyName` property.

In the sample source code, the connection string should be as below.

> ```
> # String containing Hostname, SharedAccessKeyName & SharedAccessKey in the format:
> # "HostName=<host_name>;SharedAccessKeyName=<SharedAccessKeyName>;SharedAccessKey=<SharedAccessKey>"
> ```

And you can get it on Azure portal to try again, as the figure below.
[image]

Comment: Those are hub-wide connection strings.. OP is trying to use a device-specific connection string. Those don't have names IIRC.

Comment: @juunas OP tried to run the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/5af0e09e09ae2ba41c1e6b70efa2f1d431a61a26/service/samples/iothub_devicetwin_sample.py) which need a hub-wide connection string.

Comment: Aha! My bad :) In that case they do need one of the connection strings here.